# Stacked speech editing

Tags: java, frequency, audacity

I'm making a fan edit of an artist and I want to use a clip of her speaking, but the interviewer was speaking at the same time. I'm currently in Audacity trying to manipulate the sound file with my weak understanding of sound and audio editing. From what I can remember about sound, there are usually differences in the frequency or pitch between gendered speech. Does anyone have knowledge of how I could isolate the lower/higher frequencies of the file and reduce/ remove them to better isolate her voice?[Sound file snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dthFP.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy for the brain to separate voices: [Cocktail_party_effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect).
But its very hard for a computer.
It's not simply a matter of frequency, you have to recognize the voice and filter the rest out.
For example, Google has made some progress recently in that field using AI ([VoiceFilter-Lite](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/11/improving-on-device-speech-recognition.html)).
You could try some [unofficial implementations](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/voicefilter-targeted-voice-separation-by).